# Errors in IF statement (C# Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement

I am learning C# in Microsoft Visual Studio and was trying to do an if statement but I get a red underline after the } that is after Console.WriteLine("{0} is a valid Age", a); and I have no idea why.

```
string age;
Console.WriteLine("Enter age: ");
age = Console.ReadLine();
int a = Convert.ToInt32(age);

if (a > 12 && a < 19);
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is a valid Age", a);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Age");
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Remove `;` in the last part of if

Comment: `if (...);` should not have that trailing semicolon (`;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the conditional for the if statement.  Remove it to be:

```
if (a > 12 && a < 19)
{
  // ...
```

If you're curious why the red underline doesn't appear until after the `}`, it's because if statements in C# are allowed to be followed by a single statement.  In this case, the statement is empty and terminated by the `;`. This, combined with the curly braces and Console.WriteLine, makes it so that the `else` does not belong to an `if`, which isn't allowed and triggers the red underline at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KhilanKamlesh No problem. It looks like this question has been put on hold, but I know how easy this mistake is to make and how difficult it can be to troubleshoot things when the red underline doesn't appear near the cause of the error (something to watch out for as it's _usually_ near the problem, but not always)

Comment: If this answer helped, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 0):

you have semi colon after your if

```
if (a > 12 && a < 19);
```

remove it, so it's like

```
if (a > 12 && a < 19)
```